# cv::rotate appears to have no effect

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to rotate a `cv::Mat` 90 degrees clockwise.
I've written the following snippet:

```
    cv::Mat m =  populate_somehow();
    cv::Mat rot;
    cv::rotate(m,rot,ROTATE_BY_90_CW);
    std::cout << rot.total()*rot.elemSize() << std::endl;
    cv::imwrite("dump0.bmp",m);
    cv::imwrite("dump1.bmp",rot);
```

The first image, `dump0.bmp` has the contents I expect, so I assume `cv::Mat m` is correct.
However, the second image is invalid and the size of `rot` in memory as printed to `std::cout` is 0.

I'm using OpenCV 3.4.1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how does that compile? `ROTATE_BY_90_CW` shouldn't even be defined.

Comment: True. However, in cv::rotate(), the rotate code parameter is an int, not an enum class.
There are other classes in the project to which this snippet belongs, which define ROTATE_BY_90_CW, also as an enum. As such, the compiler fails to catch this as both enums can be cast to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have wrong rotateCode, try use `cv::ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE`.

Comment: that was it. thanks, it's hard to spot this after staring at the same code too long